Is there a "clean" proof to $tr(\sqrt{A^* A}) \geq |tr(A)|$?
I'm aware this is a specific case to the general Von Neumann's trace inequality and I am familiar to some ways to prove it, but I was wondering if there would be a proof for this that required not as much technicality as for those. Besides, is there a way to geometrically interpret such inequality (aside the obvious algebraic meaning involving eigenvalues and singular values) to build up intuition? I may be wrong, but I feel, when thinking about the polar decomposition of matrices,that there may exist a relationship with the idea that, in a circle centered at the origin, the radio's length is less or equal to the sum of its coordinates.

Yes, this is easily proven with polar decomposition and an attempt is really needed by you here.  In fact one can prove a much stronger claim that $\sum_{k=1}^n \sigma_k \geq \sum_{k=1}^n \vert \lambda_k \vert$ with equality iff $A$ is normal.

Using the SVD $A = U\Sigma V^*$, one has $\mathrm{tr}(\sqrt{A^*A}) = \mathrm{tr}(\Sigma)$, whereas $\mathrm{tr}(A) = \mathrm{tr}(V^*U\Sigma)$. $U$ and $V$ contain all information about the phases of the eigenvalues of $A$ as well as the nonnormality of $A$, so there may be some way to characterize this via the deviation of $V^*U$ from the identity
